# How do I write a PowerShell script to test and copy file paths?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a CSV file of file paths. For each path, I want to test if the file exists. If it does, copy to a new location. If it does not, write that path to a "missing files" file.

This is what I have so far...

```
Import-Csv .\files.csv | ForEach {
    If (Test-Path -Path $_.File) {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) exists"
    } Else {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) does NOT exist"
        $_.File | Out-File .\missingFiles.txt -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it lacks copying? What have you tried? Does it not work? If so, what error do you receive.

Comment: Use `robocopy`.

Comment: Currently it works, but what i like to add the functionality to be able to copy what it found to new location.

Comment: Did you Google how to copy a file? `copy-item`

Comment: I did, but i don't know were to plug in to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Csv .\files.csv | ForEach {

If (Test-Path -Path $_.File) {

    Write-Output "$($_.File) exists"
    Copy-Item -Path $_.File -Destination "\\Wherever\You\Want"

} Else {

    Write-Output "$($_.File) does NOT exist"
    $_.File | Out-File .\missingFiles.txt -Append

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust the filesystem this way. A file can disappear or change permissions between your `Test-Path` and your `Copy-Item`. A safer way to do this (and you may decide you don't need this kind of safety)...

```
Import-Csv -Path .\files.csv | %{
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination <path>
        Write-Verbose -Message "Found: $_"
    } catch {
        $_ | Out-File -Append -Path .\missing.txt
        Write-Verbose -Message "Not Found: $_"
    }
}
```

Comment: Anthony, your copy may fail for a wide variety of reasons besides the original file not existing.  You may network glitch, be denied access at source or destination, out of disk space, et cetera.  Consider making your proposed file track failures, describe it as such, and include the exception text in your messaging.

Comment: I would avoid reinventing the wheel and use `robocopy` instead.

Comment: Damnit, @Bill_Stewart, you're right! The author is going to have to figure out how to translate his CSV file into appropriate input and how to capture the output he needs (I'm assuming these things are requirements in his context).